# Display battery percentage for mouse and keyboard

Tags: keyboard, mouse, power-management, battery

I've recently bought myself a new Logitech wireless mouse and keyboard set. To get these working in Ubuntu 14.04, I first paired them (unifying USB) using Winblows then I installed Solaar.

The issue I am having is that I cannot see either a battery percentage or remaining time in either Solaar or System > Power. Both places show a simple progress bar with words like 'low' or 'low(charging)'. Although I do get the occasional popup window stating that a battery is running low which DOES include a percentage.

Googling the issue has not been fruitful. I have tried editing the dconf, which is currently configured to show both percent and time with icon-policy set to 'present', yet nothing is shown on the taskbar or in the Power window.

Is there any way to display percentages?

The `lsusb` output:

> Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver

Comment: Are your devices [supported](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/devices.html)?  Could you please go to a terminal by pressing [Ctrl][Alt][T] and type `lsusb`. Then [edit] your question and copy-paste the output of the command into your question.

Comment: @Fabby I believe they are supported. Like I mentioned in the question, the battery levels are displayed in the form of a progress bar (battery icon) but percentages are only visible on low battery warning popups.

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking for is to have percentages displayed instead of progress bars at all time instead of percentages with low battery warnings!

That is something for the new version ([here is a link to the new User Interface](https://github.com/pwr/Solaar/blob/master/docs/20121210110342697.pdf?raw=true)) so unfortunately not available right now.

But looking at the activity of the project, they could use an additional hand, so if you're willing to do some programming work yourself, you can start helping yourself!  **;-)**

Comment: Don't thank me!  ;-) If you like my answer, just click the little grey **☑** under the "0" now turning it into beautiful green.  If you do not like my answer, click on the little grey down-arrow below the 0, and if you *really* like my answer, click on the little grey checkmark *and* the little up-arrow...  If you have any further questions, go to http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask